# Run query to change Pence to Pound

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I have some values in one row in a database. This is an example

```
[
    {"id":"1","value":"800g"},
    {"id":"2","value":"55p"},
    {"id":"3","value":"6.9p \/ 100g"}
]
```

This section of the code `{"id":"2","value":"55p"}` i would like in this format `{"id":"2","value":"£0.55"}` Notice the change from Pence to Pound - only in the "id":"2" section.
How can i run a query so it only changes the format for that section of code, and not the rest of the code.
Been puzzling me all morning :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure this is mysql? is the value field a string typed field?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the database section http://awesomescreenshot.com/01b3ve0dd8

Comment: Just realised I will have to run a query on the next column also.

Comment: I get it, you have a text field whose contents are formatted as JSON. I 'm not sure there's a safe way to manipulate JSON with default MySQL functions. You'll need to operate on this data using something like PHP, or (I wouldn't do it) experiment with [MySQL UDF JSON](http://labs.mysql.com/)